# UIScrollView not scrollable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to make a UIScrollView scrollable.As I've understood, the difference between the content size and the frame size makes the view scrollable to reach the other parts of the rectangle.So I've put different sizes.
This what I've done in my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scrollView= [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    scrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
    scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal=YES;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical=YES;
    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];
}
```

But the view is not scrollable, the scroll bar isn't even there is the view.
There are some similar questions but no one made me get the solution.
I got the impression that everything I write in the viewDidLoad method is merely ignored, except for setting the color.But of course the method gets executed.

Comment: are the touches of you main view enabled?

Comment: Have you tried setting from nib file?

Comment: There aren't touches enabled.From the nib I tried but initWithFrame wasn't being called, I had basically the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the view was scrolling, just in a different way from what I had habis with Cocoa so i didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

make sure to include (do this in `viewWillAppear`, because there are some strange issues with declaring this in `viewDidLoad`)

```
self.scrollView.delegate=self;
```

and also declare that your class is a `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your header somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are trying to create a scrollview without any subviews? I guess it doesn't really want to have an arbitrary contentSize if it doesn't really have anything to show anyways. What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?

[UIScrollView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: I just watched the documentation, there is not a property named contentView, how do I set it?

Comment: The scrollview should scroll anyway without any subviews.

Comment: "I guess it doesn't really want to have an arbitrary contentSize if it doesn't really have anything to show anyways" - wrong.

Comment: Maybe it should scroll also without subviews, but that solved my problem.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri cool, what exactly did you do to fix it? you should post it here as an answer and let others know, I'm sure some people will read this post through google etc.!

Comment: Sorry, I discovered that it was already working.I don't know why it wasn't scrolling, now it scrolls just fine.